# Suggestions for speeding up LEFT JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, query-performance

I have a tabled named usr_data with 40,000 or so records that I want to left join with the user's organization data (roughly 1000 records) via a select in a join, obviously this is really slow (up to 150 seconds).

I was wondering if there were any ways to speed this up? Unfortunately this is the speediest query for the sub-select in the join.

**My Query**

```
    SELECT  usr_data.usr_id,usr_data.login,orgus.title FROM usr_data
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT object_reference.ref_id,rbac_ua.usr_id,object_data.obj_id,object_data.title
        FROM rbac_ua
        JOIN rbac_fa ON rbac_fa.rol_id = rbac_ua.rol_id
        JOIN object_reference ON rbac_fa.parent = object_reference.ref_id
        JOIN object_data ON object_data.obj_id = object_reference.obj_id
        JOIN object_data role ON role.obj_id = rbac_ua.rol_id
        WHERE object_data.type = 'orgu') as orgus on orgus.usr_id = usr_data.usr_id
    WHERE usr_data.usr_id > 0 AND usr_data.login <> "anonymous"
```

**Describe of Query**

```
+------+-------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table            | type   | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | usr_data         | range  | PRIMARY,i1_idx        | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                           | 8148 | Using where              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | rbac_ua          | ref    | PRIMARY,i1_idx,i2_idx | PRIMARY | 4       | ildCPC.usr_data.usr_id         |    2 | Using where; Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | rbac_fa          | ref    | PRIMARY,i1_idx        | PRIMARY | 4       | ildCPC.rbac_ua.rol_id          |    1 | Using where; Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | role             | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 4       | ildCPC.rbac_ua.rol_id          |    1 | Using index              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | object_reference | eq_ref | PRIMARY,i1_idx        | PRIMARY | 4       | ildCPC.rbac_fa.parent          |    1 | Using where              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | object_data      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,i1_idx        | PRIMARY | 4       | ildCPC.object_reference.obj_id |    1 | Using where              |
+------+-------------+------------------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

**usr_data table**

```
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| usr_id               | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| login                | varchar(80)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| passwd               | varchar(80)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| firstname            | varchar(32)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastname             | varchar(32)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| title                | varchar(32)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gender               | char(1)       | YES  |     | m       |       |
| email                | varchar(80)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

**usr_data indexes**

```
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| usr_data |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | usr_id      | A         |       29354 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| usr_data |          1 | i1_idx   |            1 | login       | A         |       29354 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| usr_data |          1 | i1_idx   |            2 | passwd      | A         |       29354 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| usr_data |          1 | i2_idx   |            1 | ext_account | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| usr_data |          1 | i2_idx   |            2 | auth_mode   | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I've tried to make a temp-table for that SELECT in the LEFT JOIN but it didn't really speed it up any, the query takes up to 150 seconds currently, with a right join it brings it down to about 1 second. (It's the smaller table).

```
select * from object_data where type = 'orgu' returns 1058 rows.
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE rbac_ua**

```
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| rbac_ua | CREATE TABLE `rbac_ua` (
  `usr_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rol_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`usr_id`,`rol_id`),
  KEY `i1_idx` (`usr_id`),
  KEY `i2_idx` (`rol_id`),
  KEY `rol_id` (`rol_id`,`usr_id`),
  KEY `rol_usr` (`rol_id`,`usr_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE rbac_fa**

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| rbac_fa | CREATE TABLE `rbac_fa` (
  `rol_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `assign` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `protected` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'n',
  PRIMARY KEY (`rol_id`,`parent`),
  KEY `i1_idx` (`parent`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`,`rol_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE object_data**

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table       | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| object_data | CREATE TABLE `object_data` (
  `obj_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` char(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'none',
  `title` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` char(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `import_id` char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`obj_id`),
  KEY `i1_idx` (`type`),
  KEY `i2_idx` (`title`),
  KEY `i4_idx` (`import_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `i3_idx` (`title`,`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE object_reference**

```
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table            | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| object_reference | CREATE TABLE `object_reference` (
  `ref_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `obj_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ref_id`),
  KEY `i1_idx` (`obj_id`),
  KEY `i2_idx` (`deleted`),
  KEY `obj_id` (`obj_id`,`ref_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If i'm missing any useful information, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Rewrite it without the subselect and that should improve the performance quite a bit.

Comment: You mention `right join`. Do you mean straight inner `join` ?

Comment: Technically there's no 'organizations' without a user in them. so right and straight will ultimately produce the same results. I appreciate the help though, I know it's kind of hard to look at with only a small excerpt of the schema.

Comment: `LEFT` is a red herring; it was ignored by the Optimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `LEFT JOIN` you are demanding a large result set, containing a row for every item that matches your `WHERE usr_data whatever` clauses. That will take time to push to your client software even if the query planner does a great job.

`usr_data.usr_id > 0` seems redundant because your `usr_id` column seems to be an autoincrement column. Are all the values above zero?

The subselect is definitely a performance hog.

Mr. Thrasher is close, I think.  The problem is mentioning a `LEFT JOIN`ed table's colum in a `WHERE` clause: that converts the `LEFT JOIN` to a straight `JOIN`.

Try this to see if you get appropriate results. I don't understand your schema so there's a little guesswork here.

```
     SELECT usr_data.usr_id, usr_data.login, object_data.title 
       FROM usr_data
  LEFT JOIN rbac_ua ON rbac_ua.usr_id = usr_data.usr_id
  LEFT JOIN rbac_fa ON rbac_fa.rol_id = rbac_ua.rol_id
  LEFT JOIN object_reference ON rbac_fa.parent = object_reference.ref_id
  LEFT JOIN object_data   ON object_data.obj_id = object_reference.obj_id
                         AND object_data.type = 'orgu'
  LEFT JOIN object_data role ON role.obj_id = rbac_ua.rol_id
      WHERE usr_data.login <> 'anonymous'
```

Notice how `object_data.type = 'orgu'` ended up in the `ON` clause. (Yes, `ON` clauses can contain the same sort of stuff as `WHERE` clauses!) That keeps it from making  `LEFT JOIN` into a straight `JOIN`.

I'm not sure the point of this line.

```
  LEFT JOIN object_data role ON role.obj_id = rbac_ua.rol_id
```

That table doesn't seem to contribute to your result set.

Comment: I'm going to mark this correct, this is the route i've ended up going with. it's not **very** much faster than the subselect but it is noticeable. I assumed the left join was going to be costly as is I guess I just didn't realize how much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By removing the subselect and using joins, you should be able to improve the performance. The subselect is processed first, generating a temp table, which is quite a performance hit.

```
SELECT  
    usr_data.usr_id,
    usr_data.login,
    object_data.title,
    object_reference.ref_id,
    rbac_ua.usr_id,
    object_data.obj_id,
    object_data.title
FROM usr_data
LEFT JOIN rbac_ua
ON rbac_ua.usr_id = usr_data.usr_id
JOIN rbac_fa ON rbac_fa.rol_id = rbac_ua.rol_id
JOIN object_reference ON rbac_fa.parent = object_reference.ref_id
JOIN object_data ON object_data.obj_id = object_reference.obj_id
JOIN object_data role ON role.obj_id = rbac_ua.rol_id
WHERE 
    object_data.type = 'orgu' AND 
    usr_data.usr_id > 0 AND 
    usr_data.login <> "anonymous"
```

Comment: This works a lot faster than the right join, but doesn't really allow me to 'left join' (or get the user even if they dont have the 'organization' ), as the object_data.type = 'orgu' is in the **where**.

If I move that to the join 

(LEFT JOIN object_data ON object_data.obj_id = object_reference.obj_id AND object_data.type = 'orgu') 

 it's about the same speed as before.

Comment: Is there an index on ```object_data.type```?

Answer (score 1):

From the `EXPLAIN`, I see that the Optimizer decided that "`LEFT`" had no impact.  So it removed it.  Then it decided that the "derived table" could be turned into a `JOIN`.  You could have done all that.

But the real problem in performance is that the important part of the filtering is on `type = 'orgu'`, but that is buried in the 'last' table.

(Henceforth I am guessing due to the lack of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for *every* table.  And `DESCRIBE` is not as descriptive ad `SHOW CREATE`.)

Let's look at this:

```
SELECT  ud.usr_id, ud.login, od.title
    FROM  object_data AS od
    JOIN  object_reference AS r  ON od.obj_id = r.obj_id
    JOIN  rbac_fa AS rfa  ON rfa.parent = r.ref_id
    JOIN  rbac_ua AS rua  ON rfa.rol_id = rua.rol_id
    JOIN  usr_data AS ud  ON ud.usr_id = rua.usr_id
     -- unnec?:  JOIN  object_data role  ON role.obj_id = rua.rol_id
    WHERE  od.type = 'orgu'
      AND  ud.usr_id > 0
      AND  ud.login <> "anonymous"
```

I proffer it as being more efficient *after* adding the indexes below.  This is likely to be the case if `type = 'orgu'` is sufficiently selective.

Note that `role` adds nothing to the query other than verifying that a role does exist for the given `obj_id`.

Indexes needed so that it can *start* with `type = 'orgu'`:

```
object_data: INDEX(type)
object_reference:  INDEX(obj_id, ref_id)  -- (covering, too)
rbac_fa:  INDEX(parent, rol_id)  -- (covering, too)
rbac_ua:  INDEX(rol_id, usr_id)  -- (covering, too)
```

If that does not help, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` of the result.  And tell us how many rows of `object_data` have type=orgu.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the reply, I really appreciate it.

Your query runs very fast (0.10 sec), I've added the appropriate indexes too, I noticed you said that the optimizer said that the LEFT JOIN made no impact on the query, but with LEFT JOIN in the original query I do receive more rows (users that don't belong to an 'organization', roughly 800 rows.) than I do with the straight join like in your query, it took 3 min 2.58 sec though. Is this possible if it is ignoring the left join?

I've updated my question with more relevant information, thanks again for the help!

Comment: The Optimizer will ignore `LEFT` _if_ it can determine that the resultset will be the same.  `STRAIGHT_JOIN` is _not_ the same as `JOIN`.